# JFrame Taking Weird Background

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, translucency

I followed a tutorial from the Java Hub about drawing images on JFrame. Everything works perfectly except the JFrame basically takes a screenshot of whatever is behind it; ex: Eclipse. It then makes that the background for no reason.

This is what i get:

[image]
Any ideas?

Main.java:

```
package Package;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

BufferedImage sprite;

public Main(){
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
    init();
}

private void init(){
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
    try {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("sprites2.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
    sprite = ss.grabSprite(0, 0, 20, 32);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(sprite, 100, 100, null);
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

SpriteSheet.java:

```
package Package;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SpriteSheet {
public BufferedImage spriteSheet;

public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage ss){
    this.spriteSheet = ss;
}

public BufferedImage grabSprite(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    BufferedImage sprite = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
    return sprite;
    }

}
```

BufferedImageLoader.java:

```
package Package;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageLoader {

public BufferedImage loadImage(String pathRelativeToThis) throws IOException{
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pathRelativeToThis);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    return img;
    }

}
```

No exceptions are being thrown...

Comment: 1. the image link is broken. 2. I didn't understand your question

Comment: I just fixed the image link sorry about that...I just don't know what is causing the problem--the image will be helpful.

Comment: I think your app crashes before displaying frame content, code would be helpful. Also, i see `Logger.getLogger[...]` in your catch block, replace it with `e.printStackTrace()` and see if some exception is being thrown. If you see some exception, update your question with it

Comment: I changed the catch{...} but no exceptions are being thrown, I also added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application hangs due to the `repaint()` call in the `paint()` method. It is a recursive call, as `repaint()` calls `paint()`.

You need to remove it, and your application won't hang anymore.

---

If you simply remove the `repaint()` call from the `paint()` method, your graphics won't be drawn, because you are overriding the `paint()` method without calling the superclass one. It should be like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(sprite, 100, 100, null);
}
```

However, it will not display the image, because you call the `init()` method after setting it visible. Call it before setting the frame visible and it will work.

However, this is not the correct way to put a background image in your `JFrame`, you should use a `JPanel` instead:

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    int x, y;
    public ImagePanel(Image image, int x, int y) {
        this.image = image;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
sprite = ss.grabSprite(0, 0, 20, 32);
ImagePanel backgroundImagePanel = new ImagePanel(sprite, 100, 100);
setContentPane(backgroundImagePanel);
```

Also, Remove the `paint()` override to the `JFrame` and call the `init()` method **before** setting the frame visible

Comment: If I remove it, it doesn't draw the image at all.

Comment: @user2550807 Because you are overriding the paint method without calling it's super. And also because this is not the way to set a background image to a frame. See my update